# What is the recommended way to handle bugs in Celery Task code?

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery, django-celery

I've been searching for a few days to find a de facto way of handling bugs in a celery task.

In the Celery docs, we do learn about [retying tasks because of failure](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/faq.html#faq-acks-late-vs-retry).

> It’s important to note that the worker is not known to crash, and if it does it is usually an unrecoverable error that requires human intervention (bug in the worker, or task code).

...

> So use retry for Python errors, and if your task is idempotent combine that with acks_late if that level of reliability is required.

However, if my task has a bug because of faulty logic then blindly retrying will not solve the problem.

In other distributed systems, I've used a `poison queue` to store messages and then re-process once the bug was fixed. The Celery documentation for routing is pretty robust and leads me to believe a similar approach can be manually done with Celery.

Is there a recommended approach to handle this in Celery?

Comment: What message broker are you using?

Comment: @MichaelMior I'm currently using `BROKER_BACKEND = 'django'` and will be using `amqp` in the not too distant future. I confess I'm still learning Celery and Django so I might be wrong here, but I feel like my question is more theoretical and transport agnostic. Perhaps you could shed some light?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the docs:

> retry() can be used to re-execute the task, for example in the event of **recoverable errors**.

I It's a logic failure, then it's not a recoverable error (like network connectivity problems). It may just make matters worse by retrying.

That being said, you can pass `routing_key="task.poisoned"` to the retry() call to make sure that all retry'd tasks are put on a special queue (in this case "task.poisoned" but it can be anything) that you have no workers bound to. This will effectively park that task in limbo until you fix the bug and then manually start a worker to clear out that queue.

Comment: For me, errors caused by "network connectivity problems" are not unrecoverable ;)

Comment: I mean `acks_late` will not "retry" a task in other case than worker crash while the task is running.